# Overriding a pseudo element on a visited link

Tags: css

I have this:

```css
a::before {
  content: "NEW! ";
  color: red;
}

a:visited::before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">News</a>
```

I expect visited links to override and remove the "NEW!" pseudo element text, but it won't. From the inspector, it seems as though the property *is* getting overridden, but the text is still visible.

Edit: this question has been answered. There are [strict limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector#Limits_to_visited_link_styles) to styling links with the :visited class

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you, this answers my question.